# WPF UserControlA with List<UserControlB>Property

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

i want to have a user UserControl derived class with a List of objects of another UserControl derived class which i can use in xaml.

```
<UserControlA>
   <UserControlA.Items>
      <UserControlB Width=10 Height=10 />
      <UserControlB Width=10 Height=10 />
      <UserControlB Width=10 Height=10 />
   <UserControlA.Items>
<UserControlA>
```

I don't know how to implement the Items Property of UserControlA to allow this. I already tried to implemet it as a dependency property of type `Items : List<UserControlB>` but this does copy the whole xaml from USerControlB into the UserControlA.Items section.

Thanks for any Help

Comment: The Problem here is that i dont know how to add the visuals of USerControlB into USerControlA when adding them as items. The Items property does contain the UserControlB objects but i don't see anything in the designer.

Answer (score 0):

It really looks like you are "over-doing" it. You may just want to `Style` or `Template` an `ItemsControl` or `ListBox` and `DataTemplate` the Items within.

Here's some code:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
                    <!--The control functionality of UserControlA-->
            <ItemsPresenter/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ListBox.Template>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl/> <!--UserControlB-->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Thanks fpr your answer but i want to learn how to do this. I want to implement the same behaviour like ListBox & ListBoxItem.

Comment: @TristanHeitzinger But why? That goes against the whole WPF paradigm. Controls offer functionality. Everything else is window dressing. If you need new functionality, you shouldn't be using UserControl. You should be using  the CustomControl template and learning about "lookless" control design.

Comment: First, i don't want a look less control (see comment above).
Second, please stop asking why. This is not your concern.
I am grateful for help